# Format output text file based on data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, output

I have a data frame which is relating to a shop and the purchases its customers have made.

I want to output the data in the data frame in a certain format. 
The data frame consists of the following columns:

`Customer ID`, `# of products`, `List of Products`, `Class of product`.

Examples of some entries in the data frame are:

```
df = [{Customer ID: 00001, 00002, 00003}, 
{# of products: 3, 2, 5},
{List of Products: (Milk, Cheese, Bread), (Butter, Steak), (Bread, Apple, Steak, Pasta, Bananas)}, 
{Class of Product: {[1,2,'D'], [3,3,'G']}, {[1,1,'D'], [2,2,'M']}, {[1,1,'G'], [2,2,'F'],[3,3,'M'], [4,4,'G'], [5,5,'F']}
```

I want the text file to be outputted as follows:

```
00001 # Customer ID
3 # Number of Products
Milk Cheese Bread # List of Products separated using single spacing
D D G # Class corresponding to the products, where D = dairy, G = Gluten, also separated using single spacing
# New line

00002 # Next customer number (Next row of data frame)
2 # number of products
Butter Steak # List of products they purchased separated using single spacing
D M # Class corresponding to the products, where D = Dairy and M = Meat, also separated using single spacing
# New Line

00003 # Next customer number (Next row of data frame)
5 # number of products
Bread Apple Steak Pasta Bananas # List of products separated using single spacing, 
G F M G F # Corresponding to the products where F = Fruit, also separated using single spacing
# New Line
```

and so on for the entire dataframe.

I am unsure of how to specify the specific format of the text file, and also how to ensure that the class of the product prints correctly for each product.
As for example for customer 00001:
[1,2,'D'], [3,3,'G'], ensuring that the class is printed as D D G in the correct order with the single spacing.

Update:

```
    Customer_ID Num_Items   List_of_Products          Classes   
    00001        3         Milk Cheese Bread        [[1,2,'D'],[3,3,'G']]   
    00002        2         Butter Steak         [[1,1,'D'],[2,2,'M']]   
    00003        5         Bread Apple Steak Pasta Bananas  [[1,1,'G'], [2,2,'F'], [3,3, 'M'], [4,4,'G'], [5,5,'F']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide a definition of `df` that works? As it is, it raises type errors and without knowing exactly what is the type of your data in each column it is complicated to help you.

Assuming this block creates a dataframe with the same format as yours:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer ID': ['00001', '00002', '00003'], 
      '# of products': [3, 2, 5],
      'List of Products': [['Milk','Cheese','Bread'], ['Butter','Steak'],['Bread','Apple','Steak','Pasta','Bananas']], 
      'Class of Product': [[[1,2,'D'], [3,3,'G']], [[1,1,'D'], [2,2,'M']], [[1,1,'G'], [2,2,'F'],[3,3,'M'], [4,4,'G'], [5,5,'F']]]
     })
```

Then the following code should do the trick:

```py
file=open('outputfile.txt','a')
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    block  = str(row['Customer ID'])+'\n'
    block += str(row['# of products'])+'\n'
    for product in row['List of Products']:
        block += str(product)+' '
    block += '\n'
    current=1
    for classP in row['Class of Product']:
        if len(classP)==3 and classP[0]==current:
            block += (1+classP[1]-classP[0])*(str(classP[2])+' ')
            current = classP[1]+1
        else:
            print("Class of Product should be a list of 2 numbers and one letter but I got: "+str(classP))
    block += '\n\n'
    print(block)
    file.write(block)
```

Of course, since you did not provide a block of code to generate df, I cannot be sure that this will work for you.

Comment: It is still not clear to me what the datatype of List_of_products is (list or tuple?)

In any case, have you tried to simply create loops over each row and then write a short function to format each column data the way you want it?

Comment: List_of_Products is a list of lists

Comment: What is "classP" in this code? I get an error saying it's not defined

Comment: sorry I made an error while copying my code. I just edited my answer.

Comment: When I try this, it just goes into the else statement and prints each character of the string for each line? E.g. “class of product should be a list of 2 numbers and a letter but I got: [“ \n “class of product should be a list of 2 numbers and a letter but I got: 1”, etc...

Comment: This means that some of the data you have is not always formatted as you said.
I don't know what you expect when Class of Product is [1] you only explained what to do when it is [1,1,'D'].

Answer (score 0):

assuming your classes row is a `list of lists`,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer ID': ['00001', '00002', '00003'], 
      '# of products': [3, 2, 5],
      'List of Products': ['Milk Cheese Bread', 'Butter Steak','Bread Apple Steak Pasta Bananas'], 
      'Class of Product': [[[1,2,'D'], [3,3,'G']], [[1,1,'D'], [2,2,'M']], [[1,1,'G'], [2,2,'F'],[3,3,'M'], [4,4,'G'], [5,5,'F']]]
     })

>>>df

  Customer ID  # of products                 List of Products                                   Class of Product
0       00001              3                Milk Cheese Bread                             [[1, 2, D], [3, 3, G]]
1       00002              2                     Butter Steak                             [[1, 1, D], [2, 2, M]]
2       00003              5  Bread Apple Steak Pasta Bananas  [[1, 1, G], [2, 2, F], [3, 3, M], [4, 4, G], [...
```

Now iterate through each row using [pandas.DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas-dataframe-iterrows) and save to a text file

```
with open('/path_to_file/file_nmae.txt','a')as fp:
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        for i,value in enumerate(row):
            if i==3:
                extract =''
                for item in value:
                    if item:
                        extract+= ((item[1]-item[0]+1) * item[2])
                value = ' '.join(extract)
            else:
                if not isinstance(value, str):
                    value = str(value)

            fp.write(value+'\n')
```

output

```
00001
3
Milk Cheese Bread
D D G
00002
2
Butter Steak
D M
00003
5
Bread Apple Steak Pasta Bananas
G F M G F
```

Comment: When I do this, I receive an error ```string index out of range``` at the line ```extract+= ((item[1]-item[0]+1) * item[2])```